# I am using tawk.to chat widget. Can I send email and username using code automatically without asking user any detail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, chat, tawk.to

Actually my user is already authenticated. When he opens up chat window, I don't want him to fill up form which includes email and name. Email and name should send automatically. I have tried to send data but its still empty there. I have tried various methods but nothing worked well. Let me know if I have missed something in it.
Thank you
[tawk.to dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDnHf.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... Your other head elements ... -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- ... Your other body elements ... -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {};
      var Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();

      Tawk_API.onBeforeLoad = function () {
        Tawk_API.setAttributes({
          name: 'Johny Doe', // Replace with the visitor's name
          email: 'johny@example.com', // Replace with the visitor's email
          custom_param1: 'value1',
          custom_param2: 'value2',
          // ...
        });
      };

      Tawk_API.onChatStarted = function () {
        // Send the visitor's email and name when the chat starts
        Tawk_API.setAttributes({
          name: 'Johny Doe', // Replace with the visitor's name
          email: 'johny@example.com', // Replace with the visitor's email
          // Add any other custom attributes as needed
          custom_param1: 'value1',
          custom_param2: 'value2',
          // ...
        });
      };

      (function () {
        var s1 = document.createElement('script'),
          s0 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s1.async = true;
        s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/64be723694cf5d49dc66135c/1h63us9e2';
        s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I have tried various methods` What exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

From the Tawk.to docs

https://help.tawk.to/article/setting-a-visitors-name-and-email-in-the-pre-chat-form-using-javascript-api

With Secure JavaScript API Enabled and the user’s name and email available on widget load, use the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{};
Tawk_API.visitor = {
name : 'visitor name',
email : 'visitor@email.com',
hash : 'hash-value'
};

var Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
<!-- rest of the tawk.to widget code -->
</script>
```